# Getting Rbenv Error on Site That Uses RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-5, rbenv

I have a Rails 5.1.3 project I have been working on for quite some time, but had to take a little time off. I came back to it today to do some more work on it, but it's giving me a rbenv error. The strange thing is I have never used rbenv with this site, only rvm. Here is the error, which comes up when I run bundle install:

```
rbenv: version `2.4.1' is not installed
```

I have no idea why this would come up. When I run "which ruby" I get this (which is obviously pointing to my rvm):

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby
```

This is the correct version of Ruby for this project. I'm not sure what is happening. I am running this on a MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

This was dumb. I just ran rvm use 2.4.1 even though it said that was what it was using, but it worked. Bundler ran fine after that.